# Predictable Network Interface Names

Tags: networking, systemd, pci, devices

So, I've been looking into this systemd "Predictable Network Interface Names" for quite some time and got some understanding on how it works, but I can't for the love of Thor figure out the naming scheme with **enp***X***s***Y*, I know that it's supposed to indicate the physical location of the device, but what exactly does the *X* and *Y* mean? Which one is the physical location? What exactly does the other indicate, a bus index, perhaps? I have no idea and really want to know.
I searched high and low and could find nothing explaining in detail how this naming scheme works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is described in the man page [systemd.net-naming-scheme](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html) in later systemd versions. `en` means ethernet, `p` means pci, *X* is the bus number, `s` means slot, *Y* is the slot number.

Comment: Thanks.
For some reason that specific page escaped me.